# Union two tables with different column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1oXi.png)

As you can see from the results table, the union hasn't worked properly as there is more than one row for each make of car e.g. Toyota is listed for NG and KE in row 1 and for SA in row 3. Does anyone know how to join these tables more successfully?
Thank you!

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you, and images of code is severely frowned upon: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). As for the problem, you need to explain more. The `UNION ALL` has worked correctly from what you have.

Comment: In simple terms, `UNION ALL` puts together all results from both of your queries in to one result. It doesn't do any mathematical operation on a result set.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about making your last query another CTE, then grouping and summing the cnt on the new CTE?

```
WITH combined AS (
select title FROM  autochek_ng
union all
select title FROM autocheck_kenya)

,   brands AS (
SELECT LEFT(title, CHARINDEX(' ' , title)) as brand
FROM combined )

,   aggregate  as (

select brand, count(brand) as cnt
from brands
group by brand

UNION ALL

select make as brand, count(make) as cnt
from south_africa5000
group by make)

select brand, sum(cnt) cnt
from aggregate
group by brand
```